# isues collecting on mutableStateFlow for unit test- After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing kotlinx.coroutines.test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, junit, kotlin-flow

I have a unit test for my Viewmodel, it is working fine for the first viewstate (Loading)through viewmodel.viewstate.first.  But when I try to collect like the following viewmodel.viewstate.collect{} I am getting the follwoing Error. It was livedata earlier in my code, i used viewModel.viewState.observeForever {} and was working perfectly, then changed from livedata to mutableStateflow.

```html
After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$3$3.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:342)
    (Coroutine boundary)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTestCoroutine(TestBuilders.kt:326)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt$createTestResult$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuildersJvm.kt:13)
Caused by: kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$3$3.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:342)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:12)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:166)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest(TestBuilders.kt:154)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:147)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.renarosantos.ecommerceapp.product_list.presentation.ProductListViewModelTest.Load method correctly when creates the viewState(ProductListViewModelTest.kt:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Here is the code for unit test

```html
   
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class ProductListViewModelTest{

    @get:Rule
    var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private val dispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    private lateinit var viewModel: ProductListViewModel
    private val repository = mockk<ProductRepository>()
    private val addOrRemoveFromWishListUseCase = mockk<AddOrRemoveFromWishListUseCase>()
    private val isProductInWishListUseCase = mockk<IsProductInWishListUseCase>()
    private val listOfProducts = (0..2).map{
        Product("title", "description", 6.0, "", "id-$it")
    }

    private val lisOfProductCardList = (0..2).map {
        ProductCardViewState(it.toString(),"title","desc","3.0","",false)
    }
    @Before
    fun setup(){
        coEvery { isProductInWishListUseCase.execute(any()) }returns false
        coEvery {
            isProductInWishListUseCase.execute("id-1")
        }returns true
        coEvery {
            repository.getProductList()
        }returns AsyncResult.Success(listOfProducts)

        viewModel = ProductListViewModel(
            repository,
            addOrRemoveFromWishListUseCase,
            isProductInWishListUseCase ,
            dispatcher
        )
    }

    //This test working fine
    @Test
    fun `initial state is Loading`() = runTest {
        val viewModel = ProductListViewModel(repository,
            addOrRemoveFromWishListUseCase,
            isProductInWishListUseCase ,
            dispatcher)

        val actualState = viewModel.viewState.first()

        Assert.assertEquals(ProductListViewState.Loading, actualState)
    }

    //Not working
    @Test
    fun `Load method correctly when creates the viewState`() = runTest {
        val values = mutableListOf<ProductListViewState>()

        viewModel.viewState.collect{

            values.add(it)
        }
            viewModel.loadProductList()
            dispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()
            assert(values[0] is ProductListViewState.Loading)
            assert(values[1]==
                    ProductListViewState.Content(
                        (0..2).map {
                            ProductCardViewState(
                                "id-$it",
                                "title",
                                "description",
                                "US $ 6.0",
                                "",
                                it == 1
                            )
                        }
                    ))
    }
}
```

viewmodel

```html
@HiltViewModel
class ProductListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ProductRepository,
    private val addOrRemoveFromWishListUseCase: AddOrRemoveFromWishListUseCase,
    private val isProductInWishListUseCase: IsProductInWishListUseCase,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main

) : ViewModel() {

    // Backing property for internal mutable state.
    private val _viewState = MutableStateFlow<ProductListViewState>(ProductListViewState.Loading)
    val viewState: Flow<ProductListViewState>
        get() = _viewState


    fun loadProductList() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            _viewState.value=ProductListViewState.Loading
            // Data call to fetch products
            when (val productList = repository.getProductList()) {
                is AsyncResult.Error -> _viewState.value = ProductListViewState.Error

                is AsyncResult.Success ->

                    _viewState.value =
                        ProductListViewState.Content(
                            productList.data.map {
                                ProductCardViewState(
                                    it.productId,
                                    it.title,
                                    it.description,
                                    "US $ ${it.price}",
                                    it.imageUrl,
                                    isProductInWishListUseCase.execute(it.productId)
                                )
                            }
                        )

            }
        }
    }
```